# Find features inside a buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, arcgis-10.4

I want to find features that are inside a buffer around a line. The idea is to find how far along the line the intersection with the housepolygons happens. I have tried the intersect tool with using a distance in XY Tolerance for 10 m (the buffer distance), but it does not return the desired output.

[image: Buffer around line for points]

In the image above I want all the blue areas to get a point and to join it along the line using the "Locate features along routes tool". The projection is utm 33N wgs 84.

Comment: You could split the line into short intervals (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000017659) then use spatial join to join blue polygon that are within a distance (buffer width).

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact version of software in use, the coordinate system in which your data exists, the exact parameters you provided (offhand, using a very large XY Tolerance seems to be wrong), and a more complete description of the output.

Comment: Why do you use XY tolerance of 10m when the buffer distance is 10m? And by "blue polygons", you mean the house polygons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the function of XY tolerance is completely different than what you are trying to achieve. What I would do is as follows:

- Use Select Features by Location to select the blue polygons intersecting with the line features by applying a search distance of 10 metres
- Convert selected polygons to points (as a new point feature class)
- Use Near tool to find distance between these points and the line features
- Find the maximum distance from these points to the lines, say it is 25 metres
- Use Locate Features Along Routes tool by introducing slightly larger Search Radius, say 26 metres.

Comment: Good answer. I used buffer -> clip -> Feature to points -> Locate features along route with 11 meters. Thank you.

By the way, what does the XY tolerance do? Im not an native english speaker.

Comment: I think [this link](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=feature%20class%20basics) explains the best. If you scroll half way down, it talks about two interrelated concepts, resolution and tolerance. The same help page for the version 10.2 adds that "This value is used in relational and topological operations *(meaning if you edit the data or use one of the overlay tools)* when determining whether two points are close enough to be given the same coordinate value or if they are far enough apart to each have their own coordinate value."